# Radzen DataGrid Custom Filtering

Tags: filter, datagrid, blazor, radzen

I am moving to Blazor and attempting to work out how to use custom filtering in Radzen's DataGrid. Here is an example of what I am looking to do (from the old app I need to migrate):

[image]

As you can see, there is a filtering section above the grid. Of course I know that Radzen has built-in filtering in the grid itself, but that doesn't help when the filter you want to apply is to a column that is not visible on the grid..

So basically: how do you filter on columns that are not in the grid? I am using OData.. if there is a way I can modify the OData filter when the search button is clicked and reload the grid, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked out a solution. You can see it here: https://forum.radzen.com/t/radzen-datagrid-custom-filtering/9448/12

Basically I copied their code from /Radzen.Blazor/QueryableExtension.cs and modified the  `ToODataFilterString()` method to use a collection of `FilterDescriptor` instead of `RadzenGridColumn<T>`.. As the name implies, it returns an OData query string.. which I use to filter the grid's data. A working example, with full source code can be found here: https://github.com/gordon-matt/Extenso/tree/develop/Demos/Demo.Extenso.AspNetCore.Blazor.OData

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I misunderstood you. As you said, when search button clicked you can load data from the DB by using oData filter and reload the Radzen data grid.

then just call `StateHasChanged();`

Comment: There is no any Radzen way. You must use your own implementation to achieve that. But you can look on [this](https://blazor.radzen.com/datagrid-filter-template)

Comment: See my answer for the solution

Comment: Great! that will help me too..

Comment: Can I somehow catch built-in OnFilterKeyPress? I couldn't manage.